# How to configure spring-data-mongodb to use a replica set via properties

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently writing an application which should use a replica set of MongoDB. It is a Spring Boot based application and the following properties work perfectly fine to connect to one server:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=demo
```

This is absolutely fine for my local dev environment. But later on it should run against a MongoDB replica set, so I have to provide at least 2, better 3 replica set seeds, but how can I do this with properties?

I had a look on this page: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html, but there is no explicit property for replica sets mentioned.
Providing a comma separated list of addresses like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1,127.0.1.1,127.0.2.1
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongo://127.0.0.1,mongo://127.0.0.1:27018
```

(I tried one after another.)

This is also not working (in fact, it produces an exception which lets Spring uses the default configuration).

I also tried to use the following config.xml, with no luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo id="replicaSetMongo" replica-set="127.0.0.1:27017,localhost:27018"/>

</beans>
```

I know that the above configs are slightly different, but what I am currently trying is to get an exception which is showing me that no replica set node was reachable.

Any ideas, hints?

Comment: If you are using mongo atlas, this post will be helpful - https://www.opencodez.com/java/use-mongodb-atlas-with-spring-boot.htm

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no explicit support for that, no. But you should be able to configure that just fine via the `uri` parameter.

We've actually updated [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) recently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephane. Which version is of Spring Data Mongo is supporting this sort of configuration property?

Comment: Ok, I finally got some time to check this. It seems to work. But the log messages are not very clear about clusters (hopefully I will find some time to investigate and log an issue) Anyway, thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem and I dug into the `MongoProperties::createMongoClient()` code and found that the code was ignoring the uri value if there were any values configured for `spring.data.mongodb.host`, `spring.data.mongodb.port`, `spring.data.mongodb.username` or `spring.data.mongodb.password`.

If I put all that information in the URI (and removed all the other `spring.data.mongodb.*` values from the property file), the connection code worked.

The URI property setting ended up looking like this:

```
mongodb://username:mypasswd@hostname1:27017,hostname2:27017,hostname3:27017/dbname
```

The docs for formatting your URI value are [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I completely forgot to add this. Indeed, if any of the mentioned values is set, the URI is ignored.

Comment: can you please tell where to add authentication database name in here?

Comment: when connecting to a replica set reads by default will be done from primary node unless explicitly  specified to read from secondary right?

Comment: does the replset option flag has to be specified?. What happens if not specified?

Answer (score 9):

**Change application.properties from this:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=server1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=system
spring.data.mongodb.database=database
```

**...to this:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@server1:port,server2:port/database
```