# Spring with mongo-java-driver Use Azure Cosmos DB as MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to use Azure **Cosmos DB** instead of **MongoDB** with my **Spring boot** app.

Currently, I'm using the `mongo.host/database/port` properties. I couldn't find where I can set the **SSL** option and **replicaSet** or alternatively the full client **URI**.

This is the code they suggesting and it's working, but it's not helping me...

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
    new MongoClientURI("mongodb://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb"));
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to use Azure Cosmos DB instead of MongoDB"* -- this is not a wise idea. Despite all claims of "compatibilty", an apple is simply not an orange. If you want to use XYZ Database engine then I strongly suggest you actually use the native API of XYZ database engine. Some things will work, and others will not. Most reports lean heavily on the "not" and it does not escape notice that once available published "compatibility matrix" details are now very difficult if not impossible to find. Compatibility layers are not a new thing. And historically they never live up to claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try just using the "spring.data.mongodb.uri" property instead of specifying the host/database/port separately?

The official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) also recommends this approach while connecting to replica-sets.

This issue is also discussed at [How to configure spring-data-mongodb to use a replica set via properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839777/how-to-configure-spring-data-mongodb-to-use-a-replica-set-via-properties)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the URI and now it's working. 
The problem was that I override AbstractMongoConfiguration bean with my test sources by mistake, that is why the parameters were not working.